# IOS app with data stored in server - how to implement facebook user registration (from server or app?)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, ios5

I am building an IOS app, which doesnt have any data with it. When it wants to show friends list for example, it will request server for the json data etc..

So, how can I implement facebook registration for this?

What I assume:

The app(via ios code) does everything required for facebook user registration and finally sends the json data(like name, email, gender etc) to the server

or

Registration things will be done via server ?

Will provide more information if necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

if you don't have any data which you need to get from you server, just use [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

If you need to get some additional info from you server (e.g. you create an app for your website, where you have Facebook login functionality) you can do the following:

1) use Facebook iOS SDK to login to your app. Get Facebook access token.

2) request your server with this Facebook token. check whether you have a user with this token.

3) generate your own token and send it as a response to the application.

3) use your own token for other requests to the server.

Answer (score 4):

FB auth is done on the client, easiest way is using the FB SDK for iOS. When auth succeeds your app will have a FB access token that you can send to your server. The server can then make FB API requests using this access token.

You can also, of course, make FB API calls from the app using the same access token.

Your server should also store the Facebook user ID (acquired via the FB API or passed from your app) to link your user account object with the appropriate FB user.

Comment: Good answer. I think its silly that they put all that documentation there but not mention once that you will have to compare the user id's of the tokens. It makes sense, but makes it clearer when they make their intentions more obvious.